# Rendering recursive HTML using ngTemplateOutlet in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, recursion

I have a project that will need to recursively render HTML on to a page. To do this, I am storing the format of the HTML in a nested object array. Given the consideration that HTML is an assortment of nested rows and columns, an example of something I'd need to render would look like this:

[image]

This layout correlates to the data I receive from the database (where `size` is the width a column spans its parent row and `blocks` are `divs` that contain content inside a column):

```
var response = [
  {
    "uid": "a",
    "order": 0,
    "layout": {
      "rows": [
        {
          "uid": "qz",
          "columns": [
            {
              "uid": "ugjm",
              "size": 6,
              "blocks": [ // NOTE: BLOCK WITH A COLUMN AS PARENT
                {
                  "uid": "bh",
                  "data": {
                    "content": "row qz, column ugjm, block bh"
                  },
                  "type": 2,
                  "order": 0
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "uid": "plm",
              "size": 6,
              "rows": [ // NOTE: ROW WITH A COLUMN AS PARENT
                {
                  "uid": "bzx",
                  "columns": [
                    {
                      "uid": "1cd",
                      "size":  6,
                      "blocks": [
                        {
                          "uid": "nbv",
                          "data": {
                            "content": "row qz, row bzx, column 1cd, block nbv"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
      ],
      "columns": 12
    },
  }
]
```

I found a great article about rendering recursive data using `ngTemplateOutlet`. Link: https://trungk18.com/experience/angular-recursive-view-render/ but it appears to rely on the nested model being an exact match to the parent, and as you can see in the image above, **columns can either contain rows OR blocks**.

For example, in my data one possible path to a content block could be:

> row -> column -> block -> content

or it could be nested further:

> row -> column -> row -> column -> block -> content

so I'm not quite sure how to account for this in my recursive method to display the HTML on the page. The article I linked uses `ngTemplateOutlet` and I figured this would be a good way to start, but I'm not sure how to utilize this to account for unknown nesting depths!

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ $implicit: list }"></ng-container>
</ul>

<ng-template #recursiveListTmpl let-list>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
     {{ item.title }} 
    <ul *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

Thanks!